# javascript to PHP communication issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok, so i have a website that is designed to be able to remotely control the GPIO (general purpose in/out) pins on the Raspberry Pi it is running on using the library WiringPi. the problem is, between a javascript and a php code, the HTTPrequest.responseText always returns undefined. index.php reads the pins and prints out their states:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Raspberry Pi Home Automation</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black;">
 <?php 

// Define your username and password 
$username = "[not giving you my username]"; 
$password = "[or password]"; 

if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 

?> 

<h1 style="color: white">Login</h1> 

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<p style="color: white"><label for="txtUsername">Username:</label> 
<br /><input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" /></p> 

<p style="color: white"><label for="txtpassword">Password:</label> 
<br /><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" /></p> 

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></p> 

</form> 

<?php 

} 
else { 

?> 
 <?php
 //this php script generate the first page in function of the gpio's status
 $status = array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
    //set the pin's mode to output and read them
     if ($i != 5){
      system("gpio mode ".$i." out");
     } else {
      system("gpio mode ".$i." in");
     }
    exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );
    //if off
    if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {
    echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/off/off_".$i.".jpg' alt='off'/>");
    }
    //if on
    if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {
    echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/on/on_".$i.".jpg' alt='on'/>");
    }    
 }
 ?>
<?php 


} 

?>

 <!-- javascript -->
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

that works fine--then theres the javascript, which adds the click action event listener to all the images, except for number 5: this is one i want to update with the status of the Pi pin when it is clicked, instead of writing it to the opposite state (like the others).

```
//JavaScript, use pictures as buttons, sends and receives values to/from the Rpi
//These are all the buttons
var button_0 = document.getElementById("button_0");
var button_1 = document.getElementById("button_1");
var button_2 = document.getElementById("button_2");
var button_3 = document.getElementById("button_3");
var button_4 = document.getElementById("button_4");
var button_5 = document.getElementById("button_5");
var button_6 = document.getElementById("button_6");
var button_7 = document.getElementById("button_7");


//this function sends and receives the pin's status
function change_pin (pin, status) {
//this is the http request
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( "GET" , "gpio.php?pin=" + pin + "&status=" + status );
request.send(null);
//receiving information
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        return (request.responseText);
    }
//test if fail
    else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 500) {
        alert ("server error");
        return ("fail");
    }
//else 
    else { return ("fail"); }
}
}

//these are all the button's events, it just calls the change_pin function and updates the page         in function of the return of it.
button_0.addEventListener("click", function () { 
//if off
if ( button_0.alt === "off" ) {
    //use the function
    var new_status = change_pin ( 0, 0);
    if (new_status !== "fail") { 
        button_0.alt = "on"
        button_0.src = "data/img/on/on_0.jpg"; 
        return 0;
        }
    }
//if on
if ( button_0.alt === "on" ) {
    //use the function
    var new_status = change_pin ( 0, 1);
    if (new_status !== "fail") { 
        button_0.alt = "off"
        button_0.src = "data/img/off/off_0.jpg"; 
        return 0;
        }
    }
} );
```

all of the other event listener functions look the same as the one above, except for this one:

```
button_5.addEventListener("click", function () { 

var new_status = change_pin ( 5, 0);

if (new_status == "yes") 
{ 
    button_5.alt = "on"
    button_5.src = "data/img/on/on_5.jpg"; 
    return 0;
} 
else if (new_status == "no")
{
    button_5.alt = "off"
    button_5.src = "data/img/off/off_5.jpg";
    return 0;
}
else if (new_status == "fail"){
   return 0; 
} else {
 alert("return fail " + new_status);   
}
} );
```

i had the php code for this return a string representing the status (that i made up), to eliminate the possiblity of type issues: it didnt work. here is the gpio.php:

```
<!-- This page is requested by the JavaScript, it updates the pin's status and then print it -->
<?php
//Getting and using values
if (isset ($_GET["pin"]) && isset($_GET["status"]) ) {

$pin = strip_tags($_GET["pin"]);
$status = strip_tags($_GET["status"]);

//Testing if values are numbers
if ( (is_numeric($pin)) && (is_numeric($status)) && ($pin <= 7) && ($pin >= 0) && ($status ==     "0") || ($status == "1") ) {
    if ($pin != 5){
        //set the gpio's mode to output     
        system("gpio mode ".$pin." out");

        //set the gpio to high/low
        if ($status == "0" ) {
            $status = "1";
        }
        else if ($status == "1" ) {
            $status = "0";
        }
        system("gpio write ".$pin." ".$status );
    }

    //reading pin's status
    $status = array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for ($i = $pin; $i == $pin; $i++) {
        exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );

        if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {
            echo ("no");
        } else if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {
            echo ("yes");
        } else {
            echo ("fail");
        }
    }

} 
else {
    echo ("fail");
}
} //print fail if cannot use values
else {
echo ("fail");
}
?>
```

i even created a redundant for loop that only runs once to make sure the variable $status was returned correctly. i have exhausted what, according to others with this issue, seems to be the only possibilities. any criticism is helpful at this point, thanks in advance (and for putting up with so much code).

Comment: Any console errors? Does the PHP return correct stuff when run from location bar instead of script?

Comment: yes, the wiringpi library does what the developer said exactly: returns an integer 1 or 0 representing the state of the pin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

exec ("gpio read ".$i, $status[$i], $return );

Should not the comma after .$i, be a period as below?

exec ("gpio read ".$i. $status[$i], $return );

Comment: i was under the impression that status was the second argument in the commands sent to the exec function: the first being the string with the command.